# Finding the three most distant points

Tags: logic, distance

This question is more of a logic one.

If I have 18 points (in a 17 dimensional space) and I know the euclidean distance between all possible pairs, if I wanted to find the three most distant points would the following work:

The three farthest points should create a triangle with the largest area if connected. So if I simply cycle through all possible triples, adding up each of the sides of that triangle, will the triple that sums to the highest number be the farthest apart triple?

The fact that I am using Euclidean distances is making me unsure if this approach is correct.

Comment: How do you define "three most distant points"?

Comment: If it was a 2D plane, the three that make a triangle with the largest area

Comment: Then... are you asking how to calculate a triangle area in 17D space?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128991/how-to-calculate-area-of-3d-triangle

Comment: But doesnt Euclidean distance not compact the number of dimensions? So am no longer dealing with a 17D space?

Comment: What's your question? [edit] your question please. SO is not a chat site, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Im not chatting, you just don't seem to understand what the Euclidean distance is

Comment: This is old, but had to chime in and say user202729 is an idiot. He's the reason people are afraid to ask valid questions on this site. Did you ever find your answer?